# AutoMapper, moving away from the Obsolete Static API

Tags: c#, automapper

I am working in an existing solution. The solution uses the Windsor IoC. I have an `AutomapperMappings.cs` class that looks like this:

```
public class AutoMapperMappings
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration
        .CreateMap<LatestUpdateModel, LatestUpdate>();

        AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration
        .CreateMap<LatestUpdate, LatestUpdateModel>();

        AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration
        .CreateMap<DownloadLinkModel, DownloadLink>();

        AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration
        .CreateMap<DownloadLink, DownloadLinkModel>();

        AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration
        .CreateMap<NavigationElementModel, NavigationElement>();

        AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration
        .CreateMap<NavigationElement, NavigationElementModel>();

        AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration
        .CreateMap<Promobox, PromoboxModel>();

        AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration
        .CreateMap<PromoboxModel, Promobox>();
    }
}
```

In my `Global.asax`, I had the following:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IoCContainer();
    ConfigureAutoMapperMappings();
}

protected virtual void ConfigureAutoMapperMappings()
{
    AutoMapperMappings.Configure();
}
```

The above is giving me a warning saying that I should move away from the static API. So I Googled around and did some reading that suggested I change my `AutomapperMappings.cs` to this:

```
public class AutoMapperMappings
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<LatestUpdateModel, LatestUpdate>();
            cfg.CreateMap<LatestUpdate, LatestUpdateModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<DownloadLinkModel, DownloadLink>();
            cfg.CreateMap<DownloadLink, DownloadLinkModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<NavigationElementModel, NavigationElement>();
            cfg.CreateMap<NavigationElement, NavigationElementModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Promobox, PromoboxModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<PromoboxModel, Promobox>();
        });
    }
}
```

That is all fine, but the variable `var config` isn't actually used anywhere, so I'm sure I need to do some more stuff, but I don't know what I need to change and where.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Migrating-from-static-API

Comment: Thanks @VadimMartynov, that StructureMap stuff is confusing the hell out of me. I've got none of that and I'm not using StructureMap for my IoC. Windows IoC is much simpler it seems (cause I can't see anything that complex in my `IoCContainer` method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the tutorial ["Migrating from static API"](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Migrating-from-static-API).

You need to create `mapper` object and register it to IoC container:

```
public class AutoMapperMappings
{
    public static void Configure(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<LatestUpdateModel, LatestUpdate>();
            ...
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        // register your mapper here.
        container.Register(Component.For<IMapper>().Instance(mapper));
    }
}
```

Now you can inject your mapper to the classes that need map entities:

```
public class ExampleClass 
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public ExampleClass(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        var model = new LatestUpdateModel();
        ...
        var update = mapper.Map<LatestUpdateModel, LatestUpdate>(model);
    }
}
```

This migration will helps you to make your code more testable by creating mock object to `IMapper` interface.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank You very much.

Comment: That document has been removed, both from their deprecated Wiki. And this doc is conflicting, claiming it's no longer necessary: https://docs.automapper.org/en/v8.0.0/Migrating-from-static-API.html

Answer (score 0):

I would check out Jimmy Bogards (Automapper creator) post here:

https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/

```
IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

The config can be used to return an IMappper interface which can be used easier for testing purposes, create new mappings etc.

Comment: so I change my `Configure()` method to return the `IMapper mapper`? Right now it is `void`

Comment: Create an IOC configuration which you can use to inject IMapper into classes as you wish.